# Convert JSON to nodes and links?

Tags: json, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a D3 Force-Directed Graph variant I found here https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph using JSON data on 30,000+ Steam Games.

I'd like to link games by their first 'steamspy_tags' which requires converting this data to nodes and links like so

```
{ "nodes": [
{"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
{"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1}],
"links": [
{"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
{"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8}
```

Is there an easy way to convert raw JSON to node and link data to format it for the graph?

The data is structured like so:

```
[
  {
    "appid": 10,
    "name": "Counter-Strike",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "categories": "Multi-player;Online Multi-Player;Local Multi-Player;Valve Anti-Cheat enabled",
    "genres": "Action",
    "steamspy_tags": "Action;FPS;Multiplayer"
  },
  {
    "appid": 20,
    "name": "Team Fortress Classic",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "categories": "Multi-player;Online Multi-Player;Local Multi-Player;Valve Anti-Cheat enabled",
    "genres": "Action",
    "steamspy_tags": "Action;FPS;Multiplayer"
  },
```

The graph code itself is as follows:

```
<head>
<style> body { margin: 0; } </style>

<script src="//unpkg.com/element-resize-detector/dist/element-resize-detector.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
<!--  <script src="../../dist/3d-force-graph.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="3d-graph"></div>

<script type="module">
  import { UnrealBloomPass } from '//unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js';

  const elem = document.getElementById('3d-graph');

  const Graph = ForceGraph3D()(elem)
    .jsonUrl('../datasets/developers/valve.json')
    .nodeAutoColorBy('maintag')
    .nodeVal('PosRat')
    .backgroundColor('#171717')
    .cooldownTicks(100)
    .height(window.innerHeight - 60)
    .nodeLabel(node => `${node.title}: ${node.release_date}: ${node.maintag}`)
    .onNodeHover(node => elem.style.cursor = node ? 'pointer' : null)
    .onNodeClick(node => window.open(`https://store.steampowered.com/app/${node.id}`, '_blank'));

  const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass();
  bloomPass.strength = 1.0;
  bloomPass.radius = 0.3;
  bloomPass.threshold = 0.25;
  Graph.postProcessingComposer().addPass(bloomPass);

  Graph.onEngineStop(() => Graph.zoomToFit(400));
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What structure does your data have? Without seeing it, a conversion from it to the desired structure isn't possible. Do you have a sample that you can share?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, just added it to the post now, second code block down.

Comment: Before going down the wrong road potentially, I'm assuming the node should be the game, but what will the link be? What defines the target and the source node for each link?